# Return a column which is the difference between the nearest value below the column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I keep thinking I have a solution but it doesnt work out. I have two tables, The first table has a column with rows (for example the numbers 1 to 100) The second table has (say) 3 row with the values 9, 53, 78. (these are abritrary and there may be one, two or four values)
What I want to return are rows of 3 columns: Nrs 1 -100, the largest of (9, 53, 78) which is smaller or equal to (1-100) and the difference between that largest number and the column (1-100)

Answer (score 0):

For values 1 to 8, you'll get NULL from the [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).

```
SELECT 
  N.Number, -- 1 to 100
  foo.TheValue, -- which is smaller or equal to (1-100) 
  (N.Number - foo.TheValue) -- difference between largest number and the column (1-100)
FROM
  NumberTable N
  OUTER APPLY
  (
  SELECT
     MAX(TheValue) AS Value1
  FROM
     TheOtherTable
  HAVING
     MAX(TheValue) <= N.Number
  ) foo
```